# Astro React Tailwind and Shadcn-ui component not working correctly

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, astrojs

I tried starting up a quick project with Astro React, Tailwind and of course shadcn-ui. When I copy the NavigationMenuDemo from https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/navigation-menu and import it into my layout (or index.astro) it only highlights the buttons on hover, no dropdown appears. I followed the guides on shadcn's website to start a new astro project.

Code:
https://github.com/polooner/diverse-stem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use [client directives](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#client-directives) so the shadcn (React) components hydrate in some way e.g.

```
<NavigationMenuDemo client:load />
```

You'll need to do this for any framework component that needs to hydrate to be interactive.

Comment: Wow thank you, I just started using Astro did not know there is a client directive too!